# Style nesting can be avoided in CKEditor?

Tags: ckeditor

I'd like to restrict the nesting of specific classes which were made available in the styles dropdown.

A span.my-style-1 should not be able to nest a span.my-style-2.

I was hoping to use the disallowedContent rule to at least recurse the selected elements and return true or false based on the classes applied to it's selection.

In fact it's stuck and only prints a fake element based on the first style (my-style-1).

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'my_styles', [
    { name: 'My Style 1', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my-style-1' } },
    { name: 'My Stile 2', element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'my-stile-2' } },
  ]
);
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = {
  $1: {
    elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
    attributes: true,
    styles: true,
    classes: true
  }
};
CKEDITOR.config.disallowedContent = {
  span: {
    match: function( element ) {
      console.log(element.classes, element.children.length, element.parent);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```